# Are there any news sites that allow people easily to follow the progress of stories?

Tags: webapp-rec

All the news sites I have visited post stories, but don't update them. I am not looking for a tool like Google Alerts as that would have too much noise for my taste. I want to know when something new happens, not just when somebody writes yet another article on the topic!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts).

> **Monitor the Web for interesting new content**
>
> Google Alerts are email updates of the latest relevant Google results (web, news, etc.) based on your choice of query or topic.
>
> Enter the topic you wish to monitor, then click preview to see the type of results you'll receive. Some handy uses of Google Alerts include:
>
> - monitoring a developing news story
> - keeping current on a competitor or industry
> - getting the latest on a celebrity or event
> - keeping tabs on your favorite sports teams

Comment: The problem with Google Alerts is that it provides too much noise. I want to just get alerts when there are developments, whenever another news organisation decides to jump on a bandwagon

Answer (score 0):

Google Alert is a good tool, but I don't think it's what he is looking for. He wants to follow the progress of stories. Then try http://www.newsnow.co.uk

The news gets categorized and they create separate categories. It's the tool that many journalists use to follow a breaking story. Check out [hot topics](http://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Hot+Topics).

Comment: Newsnow is very nice. I like how you can highlight the publications you like and hide the publications that you don't. I was actually looking for a tool to only give a few updates rather than list everywhere that the story is mentioned.